# Change trace (go.Scattermapbox) style on hover

Tags: python, plotly, plotly.graph-objects

I'm trying to draw a map with **plotly**,

Following this example: https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-mapbox/#lines-on-mapbox-maps-using-scattermapbox-traces

Is there a way to change trace's style of the `go.Scattermapbox` object on hover (for example change color and size)?

Moreover, following the above example: https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-mapbox/#lines-on-mapbox-maps-from-geopandas

Is it possible to change only the river's style? In this case all the rivers are in the same trace, I don't know if it's possible.

Thanks!